# Optional IfPresent and alternative else

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How can i make a single code that will either set type to `BYTES` or `SECONDS`. Here I am setting a default `BYTES` before overwritting it with `SECONDS` with the `setTypeAsSecondsIfCcTimeIsValid` function call

```
    } else if (mscc.getRsu().isPresent()) {
        type = Type.BYTES;
        mscc.getRsu().get().getCcTime().ifPresent(this::setTypeAsSecondsIfCcTimeIsValid);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
type = mscc.getRsu().flatMap(rsu -> rsu.getCcTime())
                    .filter(ccTime -> isCcTimeValid(ccTime))
                    .map(ccTime -> Type.BYTES).orElse(Type.SECONDS);
```

However I would use ternary instead:

```
type = mscc.getRsu().flatMap(rsu -> rsu.getCcTime())
                    .filter(ccTime -> isCcTimeValid(ccTime))
                    .isPresent() ? Type.BYTES : Type.SECONDS;
```

This code assumes that you have `isCcTimeValid` method.